# What's the difference between "kvankam" and "tamen"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Their definitions seem very close.

Answer (score 10):

*Kvankam* is used to append information showing a cause or motive which doesn't have the usual result.

- *mi vidas nenion, kvankam ĉio estas luma<sup>Z</sup>;*

*Tamen* means simply "in spite of that".

- la knabo estis enlitigita. La maljuna avo tamen restis ĉe sia laboro<sup>Z</sup>;

PIV (vortaro.net) has some notes about the differences.

> Inter la koncedaj subjunkcioj **kvankam** montras simplan konstaton, **malgraŭ ke** emfazas la kontraŭecon, **spite ke** aludas intencan kontraŭecon, **eĉ se** akcentas la neatenditecon de la kontraŭeco.

And

> **tamen** estas ofte akompanata de konj. (kaj, sed) aŭ ĝi sekvas koncedan subjunkcion, por esprimi pli akcentan kontraŭecon:

Answer (score 0):

The same as the difference between 'although' and 'however'.